# Is it safe to have insert after delete, using output

Tags: sql-server

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) article says:

> An UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statement that has an OUTPUT clause will
>   return rows to the client even if the statement encounters errors and
>   is rolled back. The result should not be used if any error occurs when
>   you run the statement.

Does this extend to a nested query?

```
insert into myTable_Deleted 
    select * 
    from 
        (delete from myTable_Deleted 
         output deleted.* 
         where id = 123) x
```

Is it possible to have the `delete` fail and the `insert` succeed? (ignore the use of `select *`).

Comment: Even if it weren't atomic, you could still use a transaction to create the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DML operation will be atomic (all or none).  It is only results returned to the client that are in question if an error occurs because those may returned before the error occurred.